# Java: How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on Mac Sierra

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

I read documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) and tried to use Terminal 
`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/json/file.json`
But when I open new terminal and type: `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` it doesn't display the path that I set. The program always says: The Application Default Credentials are not available.
Do you have any idea why export command doesn't work ?

Comment: environment variables do not persist across shell invocations so when you open a new terminal, the env var you set is a different shell is gone.

Comment: @pvg - So how to set it permanently ? How to make program recognize it and use it ? I did try to write inside /.bash_profile but it doesn't work either.

Comment: 'doesn't work either' is not very informative. Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: @pvg "Doesn't work" is perfectly clear here since there is only one reason to have credentials, to authorise the program for use. If it doesn't work then it's not authorised. There's also no 'minimal reproducible example' since he's asking how to do something he doesn't know how to do, he obviously can't give an example of it himself..

Answer (score 11):

I solved using the terminal command

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following commands:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile

open -a TextEdit.app ~/.bash_profile
```

After this a new window will open. Add the required environment variable in that window and save and close the window.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/k.v/Documents/h/googleCredentials/googleCredentials.json
```

and then in terminal, execute the following command,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And if you are running you program via any IDE(eclipse or STS), then go to run configuration of the project and add a new environment variable by clicking the "environment" tab.

Add name in the name field and path to the googleCredentials.json file in value field and apply and run.

Answer (score -1):

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/_____/OneDrive/fdsafsdf.json"
```

In case you don't want to modify the .bash_profile, you can create a text file such as an export.txt with the above, and run the following before the execution of your code.

```
source export.txt
```